# how to make running process run in background and don't stop when logged out?

Tags: linux, shell, command, redhat

I am running a process in remote server(redhat linux) which takes very long time.

And I need be away for sometime, I want it to be running in background and don't stop when log out.

Just like

```
nohup command &
```

Is there any method can do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `nohup`? It should do exactly what you want.

Comment: the process is running

Comment: check if you don't have a ulimit on your user that send other signal to the process than hangup signals so stoping even with the nohup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GNU Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)

those are terminal multiplexer which allow you to start a process and detach it from the console. You can then logout and re-attach later.

eg. with screen

```
screen -S title
# start your process inside screen
Ctrl A D # to detach 
logout
```

... later ...

```
login
screen -r title # re attach
```